# How do I get command+left go to the beginning of the line in terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I know I can do control+a but I want command+left. I'm using the fish shell.

I tried creating an apple script to call control+a when I hit command+left but that caused it to call command+control+a which didn't work.

Comment: Does `fish` use `readline`? If so, when you enter the `read` command, and then press ⌘←, what does it output?

Comment: Is that a command line utility? I tried typing in `readline` but fish didn't recognize the command.

Comment: No, `read`, not `readline` :)

Comment: I get nothing. command+left makes terminal switch between windows. But command+anything does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), you could save this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<only>TERMINAL</only>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_LEFT, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::CURSOR_RIGHT, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::E, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::DELETE, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::U, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::FORWARD_DELETE, VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

I couldn't figure out how to change command+fn+delete to C-k.

There's also a predefined setting in [terminal.xml](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/version_7.8.0/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/apps/terminal.xml), but it only works with the left command, and it includes other remappings that aren't really needed anymore.

You can make ⌥⌦ delete a word forward by adding this to ~/.inputrc:

```
"\e(": kill-word
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you Lauri. I would prefer to be able to do this without something hacky but this is working really well. And the option forward delete is an added bonus.